# How to set URL of simple theme plugin CSS version 0.5 in jenkins via groovy?

Tags: css, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

**The problem exists in the latest version 0.5**

In the old version 0.4 I used this code:

```
def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
def descriptor = instance.getDescriptor("org.codefirst.SimpleThemeDecorator")

descriptor.cssUrl = '...url...'

descriptor.save()
instance.save()
```

Comment: need some code with more explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [API doc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/simple-theme-plugin/org/codefirst/SimpleThemeDecorator.html), here is a possible solution:

```
def descriptor = instance.getDescriptorByType(org.codefirst.SimpleThemeDecorator.class)
descriptor.setElements([new org.jenkinsci.plugins.simpletheme.CssUrlThemeElement('...url...')])
descriptor.save()
```

Hope that helps.